# Using localized formatted string in WPF binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, localization, format

I have a formatted string in a `.resx` file like so:

```
Blah: {0}
```

How do I use it in WPF binding to fill the `{0}` part?

Comment: Check whether this helps: https://wpfglue.wordpress.com/2010/01/14/localized-value-formatting-in-wpf/

Answer (score 2):

i didn't tested it but...
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f77ab886-2def-4cef-aed3-9ced24eb5776/using-stringformat-in-a-textblock-in-wpf?forum=wpf

so i guess you should do something like this :

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MyStringParameter, StringFormat={Binding MyStringFormatResource}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition Binding/StringFormat you can also use MultiBinding element.

```
<StackPanel>
  <TextBox Name="countText" Text="4" />
  <TextBox Name="totalText" Text="10" />

  <TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
      <MultiBinding StringFormat="Select {0} of {1}">
        <Binding ElementName="countText" Path="Text" />
        <Binding ElementName="totalText" Path="Text" />
      </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
  </TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

In a real sample you would bind something else but XAML elements but this shows you the idea.